# PHP searching differences in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question, how I can search in my array specific word?
here is how array is formed:

```
$desc_list[$val['pacientid']][] = "<div class='year_".substr($val['data_opis'], 0, 4).
" filial_r15 rtgapparat_".$val['r_app']."' id='".$val['pacientid'].
"'><span class='person'>".$val['f_name']." ".$val['s_name'].
"</span><br/><span class='person_data'> Datums: ".$val['data_opis'].
"</span><br/><span class='person_desc'>".nl2br($val['opis']).
"</span><span class='doctor'>Dakteris: ".ucwords($val['d_fname'].
' '.$val['d_sname'])."</span></div>";`
```

and I want to look up for `rtgapparat_` value, for example it can contain second data:
`rtgapparat_1`, `rtgapparat_C`, `rtgapparat_9` etc. I need this, because if rtgapparat has the same value as next rtgapparat (i.e `rtgapparat_1` from the first response and `rtgapparat_1`from the second), I need to combine description which is formed by this array...
But if `rtgappara_1` and next is `rtgapparat_C` I need to display both responses...

Here is how looks response from my array:

```
array(200) {
  [0]=>
  string(778) "<div class='year_2005 filial_r15 rtgapparat_1' id='11111111111'>....."
  [1]=>
  string(617) "<div class='year_2005 filial_r15 rtgapparat_1' id='1243124312341234'>
```

and so on...

so can someone help my please?

Comment: Mate, can you format your code?

Comment: Please FORMAT your code. It's unreadable.

Comment: It a bit unreadble. Can you format you question please.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($desct_list as $key => $val){
    if(preg_match("/rtgapparat_/i", $val){
        // do smething
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to solve this problem on the phase of array creation, it is much more better then to search for desired occurrences in result array and rearragnge it.

By the way you can search for occurrences with [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

`preg_match("/rtgapparat_(\w)/",$desc_list[$val['pacientid']])`